# Problema con load animado en PHP

Tags: php, html, css

Tengo un load animado que se muestra al cargar una página.

En HTML funciona bien pero en PHP no funciona. Dejo el código del load animado.

```js
$(window).on('load', function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
   $(".loader-page").css({visibility:"hidden",opacity:"0"})
 }, 1000);
});
```

```css
body{
  font-family: 'Segoe UI Light';
  background-color: orange;
}
h3, label, h2, h1{
  color: white;
}
input{
  width: 10%;
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.loader-page {

  position: fixed;
 z-index: 250;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 transition:all 2s ease;
}

.loader-page::before {

  content: "";
 position: absolute;
 border: 2px solid rgba(250, 250, 250,1);
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border-left: 2px solid rgba(250, 0, 0,0.1);
 border-top: 2px solid rgba(250, 0, 0,0.1);
 animation: rotarload 1s linear infinite;
 transform: rotate(0deg);
}

@keyframes rotarload {
  
  0%{transform: rotate(0deg)}
 100%{transform: rotate(360deg)}
}

.loader-page::after {

  content: "";
 position: absolute;
 border: 2px solid rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.3);
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 animation: rotarload 1s ease-out infinite;
 transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="loader-page"></div>
<body>
<center>
  <h2>CALCULADORA</h2>
  <h3>Tus datos</h3>
  <input type="number" readonly="readonly" value="23">
  <label style="font-weight: 700; font-size: 14pt;">/</label>
  <input type="number" readonly="readonly" value="0">
  <h1>No puedes dividir por 0</h1>
</center>
</body>
```

Tengo esto mismo en una página en PHP, **todo igual**, los estilos, la función en JQuery y la clase, pero no muestra el loader.

En PHP este es mi código:

```
<?php

    $number = $_POST["number"];
    $numero = $_POST["numero"];

    $result = "";

    if($numero == 0){
      echo "NO PUEDES DIVIDIR POR 0";
      return header("Location: index.html");
    }else{
      $result = round($number/$numero,2);
    }
?>

<html>
<head class="loader-page">
    <title>Calculadora</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="calculator.ico" />


    <style type="text/css">
        /*_LOAD ANIMADO_*/

            .loader-page {
                position: fixed;
                z-index: 25000;
                background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
                left: 0px;
                top: 0px;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                transition:all .3s ease;
            }
            .loader-page::before {

                content: "";
                position: absolute;
                border: 2px solid rgba(250, 0, 0,1);
                width: 60px;
                height: 60px;
                border-radius: 50%;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                border-left: 2px solid rgba(250, 0, 0,0.1);
                border-top: 2px solid rgba(250, 0, 0,0.1);
                animation: rotarload 1s linear infinite;
                transform: rotate(0deg);
            }
            @keyframes rotarload {

                0%{transform: rotate(0deg)}
                100%{transform: rotate(360deg)}
            }
            .loader-page::after {

                content: "";
                position: absolute;
                border: 2px solid rgba(250, 0, 0, 0.3);
                width: 60px;
                height: 60px;
                border-radius: 50%;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                animation: rotarload 1s ease-out infinite;
                transform: rotate(0deg);
            }
        /*_FIN_*/
    </style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
<body style="user-select: none !important;" oncontextmenu="return false;">

    <h1>Calculadora</h1>
    <br>

    <center>
        <div class="forms">
            <label class="labels">Primer Numero</label>
            <input type="text" class="textbox_1" disabled="disabled" value="<?php echo($number)?>">

            <br><br>
            <label class="labels">Segundo Numero</label>
            <input type="text" class="textbox_2" disabled="disabled" value="<?php echo($numero)?>">

            <br><br>
            <label class="labels">Resultado</label>
            <input type="text" class="textbox_3" disabled="disabled" value="<?php echo($result)?>">

            <br><br>
            <input type="button" value="VOLVER CALCULAR" class="calc" onclick="return window.location.href ='index.html' ">
        </div>
    </center>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).on('load', function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(".loader-page").css({visibility:"hidden",opacity:"0"})
            }, 1000);    
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: con el php en que parte del documento lo pintas? no obsante deberias publicar el codigo con el error no el codigo que te funciona!

Comment: Entiendo actualizaré la pregunta, entonces.

Comment: el class css del loader lo estas aplicando en `<head>` prueba metiéndolo en `<body>` ( head no es visible )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no puedes colocar la clase al `head` es una cabecera unicamente la forma mas limpia de hacerlo es con `div` una para el loader y el otro para el contenido!

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
<?php

   $number = $_POST["number"];
    $numero = $_POST["numero"];

    $result = "";

    if($numero == 0){
      echo "NO SE PUEDE DIVIDIR POR 0";
      return header("Location: index.html");
    }else{
      $result = round($number/$numero,2);
    }
?>

<html>
<head >
    <title>Calculadora</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="calculator.ico" />


    <style type="text/css">
        /*_LOAD ANIMADO_*/
            .content{
                display: none;
            }
            .loader-page {
                position: fixed;
                z-index: 25000;
                background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
                left: 0px;
                top: 0px;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                transition:all .3s ease;
            }
            .loader-page::before {

                content: "";
                position: absolute;
                border: 2px solid rgba(250, 0, 0,1);
                width: 60px;
                height: 60px;
                border-radius: 50%;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                border-left: 2px solid rgba(250, 0, 0,0.1);
                border-top: 2px solid rgba(250, 0, 0,0.1);
                animation: rotarload 1s linear infinite;
                transform: rotate(0deg);
            }
            @keyframes rotarload {

                0%{transform: rotate(0deg)}
                100%{transform: rotate(360deg)}
            }
            .loader-page::after {

                content: "";
                position: absolute;
                border: 2px solid rgba(250, 0, 0, 0.3);
                width: 60px;
                height: 60px;
                border-radius: 50%;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                animation: rotarload 1s ease-out infinite;
                transform: rotate(0deg);
            }
        /*_FIN_*/
    </style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="user-select: none !important;" oncontextmenu="return false;">
    <!-- div para el loader -->
    <div class="loader-page"></div>
    <!-- div que encierra todo el contenido de la web con style= display: none;-->
    <div class="content">
    <h1>Calculadora</h1>
    <br>

    <center>
        <div class="forms">
            <label class="labels">Primer Numero</label>
            <input type="text" class="textbox_1" disabled="disabled" value="<?php echo($number)?>">

            <br><br>
            <label class="labels">Segundo Numero</label>
            <input type="text" class="textbox_2" disabled="disabled" value="<?php echo($numero)?>">

            <br><br>
            <label class="labels">Resultado</label>
            <input type="text" class="textbox_3" disabled="disabled" value="<?php echo($result)?>">

            <br><br>
            <input type="button" value="VOLVER CALCULAR" class="calc" onclick="return window.location.href ='index.html' ">
        </div>
    </center>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).on('load', function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(".loader-page").css({visibility:"hidden",opacity:"0"});
                $(".content").show();
            }, 1000);    
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias lo probé y funciona. :)

Comment: de nada para ello es la comunidad!